# "If" versus "and" in statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Let I(x) be the statement “x has
an Internet connection”and C(x, y) be the statement “x and y have chatted over the
Internet ”, where the universe of discourse for the variables x and y consists of all the
students in your class. Use quantifiers to express each of these statements.

1. There is a student in your class who has chatted with everyone in your class over
   the Internet.  Answer is :∃x∀y [x ≠ y → C(x, y)]
2. There are at least two students in your class who have not chatted with the same
   person in your class. Answer is : ∃x∃y [x ≠ y ∧ ∀z ¬(C(x, z) ∧ C(y, z))]

I am confused about whether I should use "if" or "and". In the first question, "if" is used. In the second question "and" is used. But I would use "and" in the first statement.

Comment: What does "6=" mean?

Comment: not equal to, i mistake while typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first do a different example:

Suppose I want to say that "All cubes are big"

Now, if I use:

$\forall x (Cube(x) \land Big(x))$

then I end up saying that everything *is* a cube and big: clearly not what I want: just because all cubes are big does not mean that everything is a cube. What I want is that *if* something is a cube, then it is big, i.e. I need to *first* make sure that I restrict myself to all cubes before I say anything about them:

$\forall x (Cube(x) \to Big(x))$

Likewise, in your problem, if you use:

$\exists x \forall y [x \neq y \land C(x, y)]$

you end up saying that for *any* $y$ it is true that $y \neq x$ *and* that $x$ has chatted with $y$: So now you end up saying that *all* students $y$ *are* different from $x$ ... which is obviously not the case, since $x$ is not different from $x$.

So again, you *first* need to restrict the $y$ to any student *other* than $x$ *before* you say that $x$ chatted with $y$. So that's why you use an $\to$: *if* $y$ is someone other than $x$, *then* $x$ will have chatted with $y$:

$\exists x \forall y [x \neq y \to C(x, y)]$

Comment: but we indicated that x≠y , so student x has chatted to all students y which cannot be student x. if x = y expression will false.

Comment: @Mocak  And that is *exactly* the problem!  You *first* need to restrict the $y$ to any student *other* than $x$ *before* you say that $x$ chatted with $y$. So that's why you use an $\to$: *if* $y$ is someone other than $x$, *then* $x$ will have chatted with $y$. But with the $\land$ you end up saying that for *any* $y$ it is true that $y \neq x$ *and* that $x$ has chatted with $y$. So now you end up saying that *all* students $y$ *are* different from $x$ ... which is obviously not the case, since $x$ is not different from $x$.

Comment: @Mocak I added a different example to my Answer which will hopefully make things a little more clear

Comment: @Mocak Bram is saying that one of the subsidiary claims made by your suggested statement is that $∃x∀y\:x≠y$—a patently false claim. On the other hand, the book's answer doesn't makes this claim; it merely doesn't care about the case where $x=y,$ making a claim *only* about $x≠y$ case because that's exactly what the given natural-language sentence does.